# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) without handshake

Tags: java, email, connection, protocols, sslhandshakeexception

The problem occurs with JavaMail 1.5.0-b0 and several default installations of different JDK version on Windows 11.
JDK Versions:
OpenJDK 11 current release MSI installer,
Oracle JDK 11 current release MSI Installer,
Oracle JDK 18 current release MSI Installer.

```
    public Receiver(Proto proto, String host, int port) {
        isConnected = false;
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.put("mail.host", host);

        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake");
        switch(proto) {
        case POP3_SSL:
            this.properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");
            this.properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", port);
            break;
        case POP3:
            this.properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
            this.properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);
            break;
        case IMAP_SSL:
            this.properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            this.properties.put("mail.imaps.port", port);
            break;
        case IMAP:
            this.properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
            this.properties.put("mail.imap.port", port);
            break;
        }
        this.properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

    }

    public Receiver(Proto proto, String host) {
        this(proto, host, proto.port);
    }

    public void connect(String username, String password) throws MessagingException {
        Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties);
        store = session.getStore();
        store.connect(username, password);
        isConnected = true;
    }
```

When after constructing the Receiver-Object the code tries to connect (whether we use pop3s or imaps):

```
    public class ReceiverTest 
    {
        String imap_host = "imaps.udag.de";
        String pop3_host = "pops.udag.de";
        String mail_user = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        String mail_password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    
        @Test
        public void ConnectionTest() {
            try {
                Receiver receiver = new Receiver(Receiver.Proto.POP3_SSL, pop3_host);
                receiver.connect(mail_user, mail_password);
            } catch(MessagingException e) {
                assertTrue(e.getCause().toString(), false);
            }
            assertTrue( true );
        }
    }
```

The result is always the same error-message.

Using wireshark I captured some strange behaviour:
[Wireshark capture of the connection-try with imaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU73P.png)

As one can see there is neither client nor server hello which means the protocols or ciphers are gone before negotiation - they were sorted out localy for some reason.

The same connection tried with OpenSSL:
[Wireshark capture of the connection with OpenSSL and imap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnZBf.png)

Here the debug-output from a pop3s-try:

```
    DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
    DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.rsetbeforequit: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disabletop: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.forgettopheaders: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.cachewriteto: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.filecache.enable: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.keepmessagecontent: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.enable: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.required: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.apop.enable: false
    DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disablecapa: false
    DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "pops.udag.de", port 995, isSSL true
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2022-08-30 18:12:15.162 CEST|SSLCipher.java:466|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
    javax.net.ssl|ERROR|10|main|2022-08-30 18:12:15.280 CEST|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
    "throwable" : {
      javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:240)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:527)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:332)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:234)
        at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:112)
        at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:260)
        at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:205)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:196)
        at de.computils.mailbox.Receiver.connect(Receiver.java:69)
        at de.computils.ReceiverTest.ConnectionTest(ReceiverTest.java:26)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)}
    
    )
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2022-08-30 18:12:15.280 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1754|close the underlying socket
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2022-08-30 18:12:15.280 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1780|close the SSL connection (passive)
```

Who knows how (without disabling ssl/tls) to circumvent or solve this problem?
Who experienced similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like one need to tell which protocol to use:
For pop3s the solution is:

```
    this.properties.put("mail.pop3s.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

For imaps the solution is:

```
    this.properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

The remainig question is: Why are the TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 protocols disabled?

Comment: Please extend your original question next time by an edited section to provide new information or further questions instead of using an answer. Answers are intended to use for solving the problem, not for discussion or information providing.